# C++ Error: Too many initializers for multidimentional array

Tags: c++, arrays

I have just begun practicing with multidimentional arrays, and thought I could create a map through it using characters. However i get the 'too many initializers' error and cant seem to figure out why.

```
char gameMap[5][5] = {

    {'.'},{'.'},{'.'},{'.'},{'.'},
    {'.'},{'.'},{'.'},{'.'},{'.'},
    {'.'},{'.'},{'.'},{'.'},{'.'},
    {'.'},{'.'},{'.'},{'.'},{'.'},
    {'.'},{'.'},{'.'},{'.'},{'.'}
    };
```

Comment: You are initializing 25 elements in one column instead of 5 rows 5 elements each. This is how C style array of 5 char elements might be initialized: `{'.', '.', '.', '.', '.'}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot some braces, you want this:

```
  char gameMap[5][5] = {
    { {'.'},{'.'},{'.'},{'.'},{'.'} },
    { {'.'},{'.'},{'.'},{'.'},{'.'} },
    { {'.'},{'.'},{'.'},{'.'},{'.'} },
    { {'.'},{'.'},{'.'},{'.'},{'.'} },
    { {'.'},{'.'},{'.'},{'.'},{'.'} },
  };
```

Your code was for initializing  a one dimensional array of 25 elements.

But actually you should write this like this:

```
  char gameMap[5][5] = {    
    { '.','.','.','.','.'},
    { '.','.','.','.','.'},
    { '.','.','.','.','.'},
    { '.','.','.','.','.'},
    { '.','.','.','.','.'},
  };
```

But the best solutionn here is initializing programmatically:

```
for (int x < 0; x < 5; x++)
  for (int y < 0; y < 5; y++)
    gameMap[x][y] = '.';
```

Comment: If talking about best solutions, if we assume that `char` is 1-byte, you could even do this: `for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++) std::memset(gameMap[x], '.', 5);`

Comment: @pptaszni best in termes of what? Shorter generated code: maybe but not really relevant, faster code: maybe but probably not really relevant. More readable code? Not sure. Anyway your code is wrong, it should be `std::memset(&gameMap[x], '.', 5)`. But we can safely assume that the size of a `char` is 1, this is by definition.